# Test spock of executeryQuery method

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I've been testing with spock and grails and I've had the following problem.I was trying to do the simple test of an HQL statement like this:

```
@Transactional
class UserService {
    List<User> getAll() {
        List<User> lUser = User.executeQuery('Select u.age from User u')
        return  lUser
    }
}
```

For this I used the following test:

```
@Mock(User)
@TestFor(UserService)
class UserServiceSpec extends Specification {
    void "test service"() {
        when:
        def res = service.getAll()
        then:
        assert true
    }
}
```

When I executed it, the following error appeared.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: String-based queries like [executeQuery] are currently not supported in this implementation of GORM. Use criteria instead.

    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.unsupported(GormStaticApi.groovy:880)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.executeQuery(GormStaticApi.groovy:800)
    at test.UserService.getAll(UserService.groovy:9)
    at test.UserServiceSpec.test service(UserServiceSpec.groovy:16)
```

Does anyone know how to solve it without using Criteria?

PD: I'm using the grails version 2.3.6 and Hibernate 3.6.10.8

Comment: Please don't add screenshots when text would do.  We can not search or copy the text from images.

Comment: Okay, now I'm changing them to text. Excuse me.